# How create maven alias for set of goals?

Tags: java, maven, build

I'm configuring a Maven project and want to be able to alias, like

`mvn server` - to execute `mvn clean package tomcat:run`

The Grunt task runner does it very well, but I haven't found a way to do the same in Maven. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [`<defaultGoal>...</defaultGoal>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#The_BaseBuild_Element_Set) in your pom if you like. So you can define something like this:

```xml
<project>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>clean package tomcat:run</defaultGoal>
    .
  </build>
</project>
```

will be activated if you simply call `mvn`...not really an alias, cause usually you don't need one...

Comment: I'm already using defaultGoal, but I want to create more than one alias goals

Comment: Which you didn't describe in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box I don't know of any solution that doesn't imply using a plugin. A simple solution may be adding aliases to your `.bashrc` file in your home directory (for Linux) or `.bash_profile` (on OS X) for your desired instructions.

E.g: Adding a line `alias my-alias="mvn clean install"` will allow you to execute the command `my-alias`in the terminal, obtaining the same result as running the `mvn clean install` instruction itself. Add another line `alias my-alias-port="mvn clean install -Dcrx.port=9200"`for a second instruction, and so on.

Optionally, you can execute `alias` to see a list of all your aliases and their respective instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found to this is to use a combination of:

- [New Maven 3.3 command line config support: `project/.mvn/maven.config`](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html)
- GNU Make (which then calls maven)
- Bash scripts
- [Blaze](https://github.com/fizzed/blaze)

Roughly in that order of preference.

GNU Make is especially nice because it offers bash completion.

An example Makefile for your specific example would be:

```
.PHONEY: server

server:
[tab]mvn clean package tomcat:run
```

*Replace [tab] with a real tab! See make documentation.*

Then you can run:

```
make server
```

For windows environments you will need to install cygwin or something equivalent. For Mac you don't have to but you should probably install homebrew.

Finally the [Maven Bash completion](https://github.com/juven/maven-bash-completion) albeit doesn't do aliases but will greatly facilitate typing maven commands (press tab). Many package managers have this as a package (ie homebrew has it as maven-completion).

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the following function to your `.bashrc` file:

```
function mvn() {
  if [ "$1" = "i" ]; then
    command mvn install
  else
    command mvn $@
  fi
}
```

And so you can invoke the `mvn install` with the `mvn i` alias.

Everything else that is not `mvn i` will call the original `mvn` command instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Alias-maven-plugin](https://www.smartics.eu/alias-maven-plugin/index.html) is what you are looking for.

Following the site:

> Whenever you type a command in a shell, for instance
>
> ```
> mvn clean install
> ```
>
> you could spare time in simply using an alias like this
>
> ```
> i
> ```

It has also more advantages - you could configure plugin by XML file.