# Does equivalent practice of package.json scripts from NPM exists in Java(maven)?

Tags: java, maven

I've been trying to find the equivalent of sctipts in NPM for Java and had no luck.
Makes me wonder if it's even possible, but I assume it is, it's just probably very hard to find.

My main goal is to avoid my Readme.md file containing long commands, and would like very much to have something similar with npm scripts, which would trigger a certain line based on a certain keyword.

For example, I would like to create something like this:

```
"smoke" : "mvn clean test -Dsmoke="src/test/smokeSuite.xml""
```

or

```
"smoke" : "clean test -Dsmoke="src/test/smokeSuite.xml""
```

Which would then be run by a simple mvn smoke command.
Is it possible?

Comment: you can do same thing using shell script

Comment: Not really, maven itself has few options, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425089/how-create-maven-alias-for-set-of-goals basically you need shell scripts (or write a custom java maven plugin that registers a custom goal). You can alternatively look at gradle to build your project, that's a little more flexible since you can define your own tasks but also has nothing as simple as npm scripts. I guess you could technically use them to execute mvn commands..

Comment: There are two options: setup exec plugin to run mvn and execute sophisticated commands like ‘mvn exec:exec@execution_id’, share run configurations across team - latest IntelliJ versions do that perfectly